# Maven does not run Spock tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, testing, spock

I'm trying to test my maven app using Spock. But `mvn test` does not run my test.

```
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

I tried to name test file like `*Test`, `Test*` and `*TestCase` but it does not work. Intellij run tests correctly and count code covers.

[image]

Also when I run `mvn sonar:sonar` SonarQuebe does not see tests.

`Pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6-groovy-1.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </plugin>
```

It's modular maven project. I'm trying to test one of few module.

Comment: Have you configured Groovy (test) compilation in Maven? The [spock-example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) project comes with a fully working Maven build.

Comment: Check out the [spock-example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) project, which comes with a fully working Maven build.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find an exemplar POM with spock settings:

https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/HelloSpockPom

Answer (score 1):

Your tests are Groovy files. You need to [configure surefire](http://ppettitau.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/running-groovy-junit-tests-with-surefire-in-a-javamaven-project/), so that it works with the Groovy language.

Comment: No configuration of Surefire is necessary.

Comment: I'm sure there is more than one way to do it. I'll be trying this soon, and hope to report if this is required or optional.